# It it possible to call AWS-Lambda function from Swift-App with Amplify

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I've created an iOS-App where I am using AWS-Amplify with GraphQL-Api which works just perfect.
But as Amplify offers Lambda functions, I wanted to extend my App with these.

I have never used AWS Lambda functions before. In an other project I am using Firebase Cloud Functions which I integrated with Https-Callable functions in my iOS App.

Actually I want to do the same with AWS-Lambda as I want to send some data that gets processed in a lambda function.  I've tried a few solutions but none of them worked as I am using Amplify. I also couldn't find any documentation about that

Is there a possibility to call lambda functions just like the Https-Callable functions with an iOS Amplify App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call lambda directly than you need to do that with sdk, but for client app it's not something you want to do. You need a service in the middle, if you use GraphQl go with AppSync, or ApiGateway for REST.

Comment: lambda is a service and shouldn't require another service to use.  it integrates with cognito and has worked fine with iOS directly for many years prior to the amplify shift.  unfortunately they are very late getting it to integrate with the amplify libraries and that is very disappointing.